# Web Part SPFX Yammer User Impersonation Error Issue

Tags: impersonation, spfx, yammer

I developed a webpart which uses the following configuration to being enabled to call Yammer:

```
{
    "resource": "Yammer",
    "scope": "user_impersonation"
}
```

Now the problem is that on the DEV tenant I succeed at granting the API permissions to it, whereas on the PROD tenant I receive the following error.

[image]

Is anyone able to explain me what's going on and how to fix that?